# How can I get results from my SQL database inside a PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach-loop-container

I am trying to list the ids associated with usernames from a database using an XML file that contains the corresponding usernames.

**I think this might have something to do with $conn not being a global variable
Is that right?**

I am using the following code:

```
<?php //idlister.php

require 'connectDB.php';

$xml=simplexml_load_file("names.xml") or die("Error: 
Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->book as $book)
{
    $username = (string)$book->username;
    $sql = "SELECT `id` 
    FROM  `directory` 
    WHERE  `UserName` =  '$username'
    LIMIT 0 , 30";

    if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {

        /* fetch associative array */
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row["id"]."<br />";
        }

        /* free result set */
        $result->free();
    }
}
    $conn->close();
?>
```

When I run the above code, the browser keeps working until it gets a 502 Gateway error.

I tested the same code above, replacing '$username' with 'Bill' (a name in the database), and got the same 502 Gateway error.

But when I took the $result = $conn->query($sql) line out of the for each loop, I got the results I was looking for:

```
<?php //idlister.php

require 'connectDB.php';

$xml=simplexml_load_file("names.xml") or die("Error: 
Cannot create object");

    $username = (string)$book->username;
    $sql = "SELECT `id` 
    FROM  `directory` 
    WHERE  `UserName` =  'Bill'
    LIMIT 0 , 30";

    if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {

        /* fetch associative array */
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row["id"]."<br />";
        }

        /* free result set */
        $result->free();
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

// Printed "20", which is Bill's id

How do I get results from within the foreach loop, or how do I get the names from the XML file to search the database outside of the foreach loop?

XML Sample:

```
<response>
    <book>
        <username>Sarah</username>
        <gender>f</gender>
        <age>23</age>
    </book>
    <book>
        <username>Jonathan</username>
        <gender>m</gender>
        <age>33</age>
    </book>
    <book>
        <username>Demonte</username>
        <gender>m</gender>
        <age>18</age>
    </book>
</response>
```

Connection file:

```
<?php //connectDB.php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "Directory";

// Create connection to Directory
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection to the Directory failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "<h2>Directory Connection Successful</h2>";

?>
```

Comment: How big is the file and what is your `max_execution_time` set to? Disk IO is inherently very slow.

Comment: A sample of the XML would be useful, as well as an idea of how large the file is.

Comment: It's about a megabyte, and I'll add a sample to the question in a second.

Comment: Pardon, @Vince0789, I looked but I'm not sure what my max_execution_time is set to. I think it may be 120 seconds - which I think is the default for my server. Regardless, I once handled a 7 megabyte XML file with no difficulty, so I think everything should be fine on that front.

Comment: Your code looks fine. `$conn` is definitely in scope where you  use it. A 502 error is often a timeout so that's where I'd be looking. Does it work if you cut the xml file down? Do you have an index on the `Username` field in your table?

Comment: Pardon the delay. It works if the xml file I cut the xml file down. I have an index on the Username field in the table. I think I have to make the php do the legwork instead of the SQL.